# Regex to validate test@test.com.com.com

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation, email-validation

How can I validate the following incorrect email addresses with regex in c#?

eg:

```
test@test.com.net.com
```

or

```
test@test.net.net.org
```

These are being validated as correct email addresses. Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: Those are valid email addresses, though.

Comment: Email addresses can be on servers on a subdomain, e.g. `john@server.department.company.com`.

Comment: Yea but test@test.com.com.com.com.com is not a valid email address, how do you validate that?
or test@test.com.net.org.net.com.biz.tv

Comment: These are very valid email address. Probably what you are looking for is "email verification" and not syntactic validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While both `test@test.com.net.com` and `test@test.net.net.org` are **valid**, from a syntactic point of view, their domain parts do not point to existing domains.
For this kind of test, you may want to extract the domain part you are interest in and query the DNS (see [RFC 2821](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt) and [RFC 2822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt)) to see if it exists.

Since you are using .NET, by the way, I would suggest you to take a look at our [EmailVerify.NET](http://cobisi.com/email-validation/.net-component), a leading [email validation](http://cobisi.com/email-validation/.net-component) library which can validate the syntax (according to the latest IETF standards), the domain parts and the presence of a mailbox for your email addresses.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to just use something like:

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

For a list, please see [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) page.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider this regex:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})
```

It will match all the email-address, if it did not match the email address, the email-ad is not in correct format, Hope it helps :)

Comment: This will not match valid address like `jean-françois@invalid.travel`